# Pages in swap space or page file

Tags: x86, operating-system, paging, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

When does the OS actually divide the address space of the process into pages ?

Suppose I write a program and save it. Will the OS divide the address space of the program into pages even if it is not executing and sitting idle in the hard disk ?

I read that we have portion known as swap space or page file residing inside hard disk whose size can be configured and it contains unused pages or pages which have been swapped from physical memory to hard disk.

So before the execution of the program, is the entire program copied to swap space or can it execute from any portion of hard disk?

Comment: The hard disk is not in the address space.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: There's not much more to say, directly - a hard disk (or more generally, a filesystem) is not in either the physical or virtual address space.  However, typically the OS allows you to [map files into the virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth When we execute the program, is it transferred to swap space?

Comment: Usually when executing a program the OS will map it into the virtual address space. There is thus no need to move it to swap, if the OS decides to drop those pages due to memory pressure, it can just reread them from disk if needed.

Comment: The OS is not dividing the address space into pages, it is divided by its own definition (designed by the CPU architects). The OS assigns/make use of pages.

Answer (score 1):

Swap space is the backing store for anonymous pages, or dirty pages in "private" mappings (e.g. the data segment of an executable: it was read from the executable, but changes don't update the file).

Non-modified pages in the virtual address space of a process are still backed by the executable file on disk (or any libraries).

Most modern OSes don't actually do strict accounting to make sure there is enough swap for all the virtual memory pages they let processes allocate (this is called overcommit), but the traditional model is that the OS does reserve swap when virtual memory is allocated.

> Will the OS divide the address space of the program into pages even if it is not executing and sitting idle in the hard disk ?

I barely know where to start answering this part.  Go find an operating-systems textbook (or wikipedia) and look up:

- process: a running instance of a program
- executable file: just bytes on disk, not different from any other file until something runs it.
- virtual vs. physical address space.

If a program isn't executing, there is no process and no address space.  If it is executing, each process has its own virtual address space.  (And the read-only pages are all backed by the same file on disk.)

Comment: Size of virtual memory which we configure in Windows is same as total virtual memory which can be allocated to all processes or size of swap space right ?

Comment: @Zephyr: no, pages mapped read-only from files can use that as a backing store, not swap space.  And also, Windows allows overcommit, and can run even with no swap space.  In that case dirty pages take up physical RAM and the OS has no way to reclaim those physical pages ("page frames" in some operating-systems terminology).  Well, other than using in-memory compression as a form of swapping...  Anyway, I don't use Windows so I don't know whether your "total" is including physical memory + page-file size or not, but even if it does, overcommit allows more virtual allocation.

Comment: This site says it's the size of the paging file or swap space https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/virtual-memory-low-heres-fix/

Comment: @Zephyr: no, it's the size of physical RAM + swap space.  And that's a different use of terminology than when computer scientists talk about operating system theory.

Answer (score 1):

> When does the OS actually divide the address space of the process into pages ?

Usually the LINKER divides the application into pages to establish the initial state of the program/process and writes the instructions for doing so into the executable file. The program loader allocates pages as directed by the executable.

> Suppose I write a program and save it. Will the OS divide the address space of the program into pages even if it is not executing and sitting idle in the hard disk ?

See above. The linker divides what you write into pages.

> So before the execution of the program, is the entire program copied to swap space or can it execute from any portion of hard disk?

On any virtual memory system (that functions), every page allocated to a process will have a corresponding location in a page file. On some systems, there can be multiple page files. For example, the executable file can become the page file for static data and code.

Comment: Your last paragraph is true only on systems that don't overcommit memory.  Most modern OSes do overcommit by default, otherwise we would need almost as much swap space as we have physical RAM.

Comment: Wikipedia says MMU divides the address space into pages https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit. Could you please provide a reference for the first statement ?

Comment: A page is a 4KB Block, thats it !

Comment: So the accessed virtual address is formatted as below

Comment: in x64 when your program accesses memory, it uses a virtual address for e.g. 0x7C00019280. In4 level paging (48 bit address space) the MMU reads the page tables of the application to get the corresponding physical address by decoding the virtual address like this : BITS 0-11 : Offset, BITS 12-20 : Page Index, BITS 21-29: Page Directory, BITS 30-38 : Page Directory Pointer, BITS 39-47 : page Map level 4.